# how can i access specific ints from lists and add them to a new list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

new to python so i am writing this code that takes lists and returns a transpose version of it for example

```
mat = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
mat_T = mat_transpose(mat)
print(mat)
# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
print(mat_T)
# [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

this is an example of a correct output
now how do i access the ints in a way that i can add them to a new list like the ints 1 3 5 are all in different lists but i need the in the same list and so are the ints 2 4 6 and so on if there were more ints in more lists

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access the individual values, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the transposed values and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)+`list` to convert each transposed subarray into list:

```
mat = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
mat_T = list(map(list, zip(*mat)))
mat_T
```

output:

```
>>> mat_T
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: what is zip and how it works and how map works ?

Comment: @DanielAbuSamra I added infos and link to the docs

Comment: why the (*mat) ?

Comment: To expand the sublists in `zip` so that each sublist is considered a parameter of `zip`